# Undefined index in post variables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a code and i get this error that my post isn't "defined" here some of my code:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
```

Forgot password?

```
        <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >

            <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

            <form id="loginform" method = "post" action = "login.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">

                    <input id="register-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username or email">
                </div>

                <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">

                    <input id="register-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
                </div>
                <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">

                    <input id="register-confirm-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password-confirm" placeholder="password">
                </div>



                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                    <!-- Button -->

                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Login">


                        <a id="btn-fblogin" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

also my php code it says that i get on line 7,8,9 undefined index which is weird because the post seems correct.
here is the following lines i can get error in

```
$username =htmlspecialchars($_POST["username"]);
$password =htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);
$confirm_password= htmlspecialchars($_POST["password-confirm"]);
```

Comment: that's because your entire code is in the same page and is throwing that on initial page load.

Comment: what do you mean in the same page?

Comment: I can't see this throwing you those notices other than that.

Comment: i still don't understand? my php code is in a different file which register.php while the login form is in register.html what did i exactly do wrong?

Comment: actually never mind i fixed it i had to put isset

Comment: my sentiments exactly ;-)

Comment: now my login button won't respond for some reason

Comment: you should be posting your full code then. The close answered your initial notices.

Comment: that's my full code the only thing i added was if(isset($_POST[login]{header("index.html)} to test if the button works but nope doesnt redirect me

Comment: `<input name="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Login">`

Comment: still  doesn't work sadly :(

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: i have set it to show every error still doesn't show any error